# What is the opposite of _bstr_t

Tags: visual-studio-2012, type-conversion, bstr, const-char

I can easily convert a 'const char *' to 'BSTR' using

```
BSTR bs = _bstr_t(myConstChar);
```

This works fine.

But I am not sure now to convert a BSTR to const char *.

I don't know what the function (like "_bstr_t") for such a conversion would be.

Comment: It has a conversion operator, just cast to (const char*).  The buffer for that string is released at the same time as the _btr_t is destructed so copy if necessary.

Comment: Pardon me? I don't understand this theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a true 1-1 mapping from a `BSTR` to a `char*`.  The reason why is that a `BSTR` can hold values that a `char*` cannot like embedded null values.  Outside of that though you can use the `ConvertBSTRToString` function ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewezf1f6%28VS.80%29.aspx))